# JavaScript Output Takes Over Screen, Won't Load Into Container Element via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have some JavaScript being returned by a url to jQuery.  This JavaScript has document.write(...) statements in it.  I would like to click on a link and have the *output* of the document.write(...) commands be *inserted* into a div.

It seems I've tried everything (jQuery load(), getScript(), get(), ajax(), inserting a script tag into the div with the url source specified, using JavaScript eval to try and capture the end-result of the JavaScript write(...) commands) and no matter what I do, the whole screen is taken over (blanks out/turns white) and the output of the JavaScript is the *only* thing on the screen, instead of that content ending up just in the div.

Any ideas of why this is happening and why it won't just load into the container element?

One more important detail.  If I use the url in a script tag in HTML (e.g. ) it loads the content fine into the div.

???

Here is my current view code, which loads the generated JavaScript into the div, instead of the output of said JavaScript:

```
$(function($) {
    $('#update_preview').click(function() {

      event.preventDefault();

      $('#preview').load('<%= url_for :controller => 'items', :action => 'preview', :id => @cf.id, :only_path => false %>');

    })
  })
});
```

Comment: added a code example that represents the closest i've been able to get to my desired functionality.  the problem is that the javascript should be evaluated into a string of HTML and placed into the #preview div, but it simply rewrites the whole browser window instead.

Comment: that is, it takes over the whole screen if i try to use eval() on the returned JavaScript.  any solution that doesn't evaluate the JavaScript just returns my JS code ( e.g. var txt="some txt"; document.write(txt); )

Comment: Well, I've learned that document.write(...) definitively does not work after page load, so there's the reason that this approach isn't working.  But this is the method I use for loading the content as an embedded widget on the page, so what is an alternative that would work in both situations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a innerHTML like this

```
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = returnvariablehere;

<div id="display"> </div>
```

Comment: even this takes over the screen, not changing the URL, but completely resetting the DOM and replacing it with the evaluated JavaScript that should only be injected into the container div.

Answer (score 0):

The screen was being redrawn because document.write(...) does not work after initial page load.  Thus it was wiping the DOM and starting over when the JavaScript was evaluated.

I eventually had to rewrite the server-side code to output the raw HTML and use [jQuery.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to replace the data returned by [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

In the end, you can't load JavaScript that writes to the page in that manner unless it is guaranteed to load as the initial page is rendering.